# the return type of lower_bound and upper_bound if key value not found

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

I have a confusion about the returned value from the `lower_bound` and `upp_bound` member function from C++ STL containers. According to chapter 11.3.5 of "C++ Primer 5th Edition":

"if the element is not in the multimap, then lower_bound and upper_bound will rerturn equal iterators; both will refer to the point at which the key can be inserted without disrupting the order...If the element we're looking for has the largest key in the container, then upper_bound on that key returns the off-the-end iterator."

So if we have a `multimap<int, int>` with keys `{1, 2, 3}`, and we want to look for the element with key value `4`, then the returned value of both `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are iterators pointing to the position after `3`, because `4` is larger than any existing key values in the `multimap`.

For the same reason, if we're looking for the element with the key value `0`, then both the first element with the key value `1`, because we can insert this element there in front of the one with the key value `1` "without disrupting the book" according to the book.

However, I found another file about the `lower_bound`:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound, in which the returned value of it will point to the "last if no such element is found", same as for the `upper_bound`.
From here, it seems like that no matter what the key value is, the returned iterator will always point to the last (off-the-end) in the container.

So my problem is, which one is correct, or did I make it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Full quotation from cppreference: "Returns: Iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than value, or last if no such element is found." "No such element" doesn't mean "no element equal to the argument passed to `lower_bound`", but rather "no element that value could be inserted before, while preserving order". The two sources you cite both say the same thing; there's no contradiction.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh that could be where my misunderstanding came from... I think the text from the cppreference does have some ambiguity that makes me really easy to misunderstand it as the wrong meaning. Thank you!

Comment: @kaiyuwei Actually, the formulation in cppreference is very formal and mathematically precise, leaving no room for interpretation. The text in your textbook tries to say the same thing in less formal, more accessible terms, since its target audience is the beginners, new students of the language.

Answer (score 1):

If you continue reading:

> Of course, if iterator returned from these operations might be off-the-end iterator for the container itself. If the element we look for has the largest key in the multimap, then upper_bound on that key returns the off-the-end iterator. If the key is not present and is larger than any key in the container, then the return from lower_bound will also be the off-the-end iterator.

All texts in the question are equal. `auto i = lower_bound(m.begin(), m.end(), 3)` will return an iterator pointing to 4 ([*Iterator **pointing to the first element that is not less than value**, or last if no such element is found*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)). `m.insert(i, 3)` will [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) 3 before 4, `i` is an [iterator to the position before which the new element will be inserted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert)).

`auto i = lower_bound(m.begin(), m.end(), 5)` will return the `m.end()` ([*Iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than value, or **last if no such element is found***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)). `m.insert(std::end(), 5)` will insert 5 after 4 and before `m.end()`, `m.end` is an [iterator to the position before which the new element will be inserted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert)).